# java.Util.Date object with date of different timezone

Tags: java, date

I am trying to create a date object with time representing a date-time in a different timezone. Is it possible? I tried this. Can someone please explain what is wrong here.

```
public static void test3() {

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"));

    Date d1 = calendar.getTime();
    System.out.println("d1= " + d1);

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss a z");
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"));

    String dateInString = sdf.format(calendar.getTime());
    System.out.println("dateInString= " + dateInString);

    try {
        Date d2 = sdf.parse(dateInString);
        System.out.println("d2= " + d2);
    }
    catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

output:

```
d1= Thu Jan 21 17:26:20 IST 2016
dateInString= Jan 21, 2016 06:56:20 AM EST
d2= Thu Jan 21 17:26:20 IST 2016
```

**UPDATE:**

If I dont care about the timezone and just need the time, I have a Date object with shows the time with wrong timezone. Used a new instance of SDF

```
public static void test3() {

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"));

    Date d1 = calendar.getTime();
    System.out.println("d1= " + d1);

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss a");
    SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss a");
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"));

    String dateInString = sdf.format(calendar.getTime());
    System.out.println("dateInString= " + dateInString);

    try {
        Date d2 = sdf2.parse(dateInString);
        System.out.println("d2= " + d2);
    }
    catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
d1= Thu Jan 21 18:36:51 IST 2016
dateInString= Jan 21, 2016 08:06:51 AM
d2= Thu Jan 21 08:06:51 IST 2016

enter code here
```

Comment: If you use Java 8 then look into the new date+time API.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I am in Java 7

Comment: *Can someone please explain what is wrong here*: nothing is wrong. What do you expect to happen instead? A Date is just a wrapper for a number of milliseconds. It doesn't have any timezone.

Comment: I think you are confused with the concept of time(or Date) and the representation of time. With change in Locale, the representation of the date changes but the actual value represeted by the Date object does not. When you do SOP you are actually formatting the Date object using the default locale.

Comment: @JBNizet Does it mean that you create a java.Util.Date object which represents a date-time which is not the same as the the time zone of the system where the JVM is?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
Date date = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
SimpleDateFormat sdfAmerica = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-M-yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
sdfAmerica.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"));
String sDateInAmerica = sdfAmerica.format(date);
```

Comment: You are formatting the date to a different time zone, which I am ready doing, I would like to have a Date object

Comment: Can do not be a Calendar object?

Answer (score 0):

Date is intended to store a UTC time (see [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html)). If you want to have the time for a different time zone and you don't want to format, I would suggest using `Calendar` objects (see [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)).

For u as Java 7 developer: In general, I recommend using `Calendar` objects instead of `Date` objects because of easier manipulation (e.g. adding time) and more intuitive api.

Answer (score 0):

you can solve this problem in the following way

```
SimpleDateFormat sdfAmerica = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-M-yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
sdfAmerica.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"));
Date newDate = sdfAmerica.parse(sdfAmerica.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()));
```